# Convert c++ std::string to c# byte array

Tags: c#, c++

I have a .NET program that uses a DLL export to get a name of a user.

`public static extern string Name(byte[] buf);`

This is the export, and I would really like to not change it, as a lot of code relies on it. So, I would like to know, in C++, how would I convert a `char*` array to the byte buffer?

I have tried this:

```cpp
void Name(std::byte buf[256])
{
    std::string s{ "test" };
    std::byte* ptr = reinterpret_cast<std::byte*>(s.data());
    buf = ptr;
    return;
}
```

When I print out the string that I convert, I get nothing, it is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your C++ function implementation does not match the expectations of the C# function declaration.

The C# byte array is marshalled into the function as a pinned pointer to the array's raw memory. The syntax you are using in the C++ code for the parameter (`std::byte buf[256]`) is just syntax sugar, the compiler actually treats it as a pointer (`std::byte* buf`). Which is fine in this situation. However, your C++ function is not actually copying anything into the memory that the pointer is pointing at. You are simply changing the pointer itself to point at a different memory address. And the pointer itself is a local variable, so when the function exits, the pointer will no longer exist, and it won't matter what it is pointing at.

Also, the C# declaration is expecting the function to return something that can be marshalled to a .NET `string`, but the C++ function is not actually `return`'ing anything at all.  The default marshalling behavior for a `string` return value is as `UnmanagedType.LPStr`, so the C++ function needs to return a pointer to a null-terminated `char*` string. The memory for that string must be allocated with `CoTaskMemAlloc()`, as the marshaller will take ownership of the memory and free it with `CoTaskMemFree()` after converting the `char` data to a `string`.

Also, the C++ function has no calling convention defined, so it is going to use the compiler's default (which is usually `__cdecl`, unless you change your compiler's settings). However, the default calling convention that .NET's `DllImport` expects the C++ function to use is `__stdcall` instead (for compatibility with Win32 APIs).  This mismatch won't matter in 64bit, but it matters alot in 32bit.

Without changing your C# declaration, try this on the C++ side:

```
char* __stdcall Name(std::byte buf[256])
{
    std::string s{ "test" };
    size_t size = s.size() + 1;
    memcpy(buf, s.c_str(), size);
    void *ptr = CoTaskMemAlloc(size);
    memcpy(ptr, s.c_str(), size);
    return ptr;
}
```

That being said, it is weird to have a function that returns a string in both a byte array output parameter and in a return value. Are you sure the byte array is not meant to be used as an input parameter instead, where the function parses its content to extract amd a string? That would make more sense. It would really help if you would update your question to show how your .NET code is actually calling the C++ function and using the byte array.

Answer (score 1):

When you write

```
void Name(std::byte buf[256])
```

that declares `buf` as pointer to 256 bytes, not an array. So when you later write

```
buf = ptr;
```

all you are doing is changing the local variable `buf` to now point at `ptr`.  And at the end of the function the local variable dies.

Use `std::array<std::byte, 256>&` and copy the string contents into that. Or even better return a freshly made array instead of an in/out parameter.

Comment: Thank you for your help but I do not really code in C++ how would I copy the string contents into the array as memcpy is not working?

Comment: `memcpy` will work just fine.

Comment: When using the array in the argument I do not have access to buf.data and whenever I put just buf into memcpy I get no suitable conversion function. And when I do try to use bud.data I get incomplete class type.

Comment: did you forget to include <array>?